# How to get a users' permission in Client Context model C#

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, permissions, csom

Any idea how to convert the following code part to Client Context Model

```
SPRoleAssignment currentUserRole = web.RoleAssignments.GetAssignmentByPrincipal(user);

//Go through all Role Definition Bindings
foreach(SPRoleDefinition role in currentUserRole.RoleDefinitionBindings) {

}
```

Else new approach also possible to get user permission.